# Is KPID globally unique within Sybase?

Tags: sybase, spid

**Can a KPID (as `select kpid from master..sysprocesses`) be assumed to be globally and always unique?**
(I've found that for my small sample set `KPID(n+1) ~= KPID(n) + 65536`  (2^16) but I want to know if I can assume, previous db connections kpid is unique, even if it's previous loginame and spid match a new `loginame` and `spid`)

Cheers.

BLT.

(*Already answered*) *B) Loginame: *how can I get the loginame from a current spid*? *`loginame` isn't a column in `sysprocesses`, and I can't find any table other than `sysobjects` that has a column with `loginame`, and I can't programatically get the `loginame` out of sp_who. Maybe the sql used to generate `sp_who` would help..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [these docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36556_1500/html/histserv/X23555.htm) KPID is unique within the machine. It may be unique within a cluster but this seems unlikely since it refers to an identifier within the underlying operating system.

Since it is only a 32bit value there is no way it can be globally unique.

Based on [this glossary](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36556.1502/html/histserv/X14352.htm)

> Kernel Process ID Version: 11.0 and later
>   An Adaptive Server process identifier that remains unique over long periods of time.

The 'uniqueness' of the value has some sort of timeframe but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for that, Shuggy. That's what all I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to part B)

```
master..syslogins.suid <-> master..sysprocesses.suid
```

As in, you can get the name of a connection a la sp_who by going

```
select p.spid, l.name, p.loggedindatetime 
from master..syslogins l, master..sysprocesses p
where l.suid = p.suid
```

By answering my own questions I'm helping to grow stackoverflow ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a suid to a login name by using the `SUSER_NAME()` function e.g.

```
SELECT spid,
       SUSER_NAME(suid)      AS login_name
  FROM master..sysprocesses
 ORDER
    BY login_name ASC
```